# Combine near scatter points into one and increase its size

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, scatter-plot

I have 3 variables `RZ`, `PRP` and `TC`. I have plotted a scatter plot between them with changing colours. RZ varies between 0-800, PRP betweem 0-4000 and TC between 0-100. Code and figure below:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
points = plt.scatter(RZS_P.PRP, RZS_P.RZ, c=RZS_P.TC, cmap="Spectral", 
lw=1, s = 60 , vmax = 100, vmin =0, alpha = 0.7, edgecolors= 'b')
plt.colorbar(points)
```

[image]

What I want to do is combine some of the same looking points in the neighbourhood with a PRP (± 250), RZ (± 50) and TC (± 5) [or something similar] as a single point and increase its size. This will provide a much better visualization than the scatter plot below. **Basically what I am trying to achieve is combine scatter points with near similar values (or values within a range or bin) by taking their average and then plotting it.**

Some of the code I came up with is mentioned below (though this one only increases the size of the scatter when they are overlapping and does not consider the neighbours):

```
# First defining a list with specifications as
data_dict = {250: np.array(RZS_P['RZ'][RZS_P.PPR < 250]),
             500:np.array(RZS_P['RZ'][(RZS_P.PRP > 250) & (RZS_P.PRP < 500)]),
             ....................
             4000:np.array(RZS_P['RZ'][(RZS_P.PRP > 3750) & (RZS_P.PRP< 4000)])}
size_constant = 20

for xe, ye in data_dict.items():
    xAxis = [xe] * len(ye)

    #square it to amplify the effect, if you do ye.count(num)*size_constant the effect is barely noticeable
    sizes = [ye.tolist().count(num)**3 * size_constant for num in ye]
    plt.scatter(xAxis, ye, s=sizes)
plt.show()
```

My ideal figure should look something like this:
[image]
Can someone help me with this?

**Additional Information:**
More information on dynamic coding

```
### Divide the dataset into categories first and then plot
P_range = np.arange(0,4000,500); RZ_range = np.arange(0,1000,100); TC_range = np.arange(0,100,10)

i = 0; j = 0; k = 0; 
RZS_P[(RZS_P.P_2001 >= P_range[i]-250) & (RZS_P.P_2001 < P_range[i]+250) & (RZS_P.Rootzone >= RZ_range[j]-50) & 
      (RZS_P.Rootzone < RZ_range[j]+50) & (RZS_P.Treecover >= TC_range[k]-5) & (RZS_P.Treecover < TC_range[k]+5)].describe()
[Output]:
        RZ          PRP         TC  
count   1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    
mean    43.614338   220.068451  2.179487    
std      NaN        NaN         NaN         
### For above, I want my scatter point to remain same

i = 0; j = 1; k = 0; 
[Output]:
        RZ          PRP         TC  
count   28.000000   28.000000   28.000000   
mean    104.511887  124.827377  1.982593    
std      29.474167  62.730640   0.977752    
## For this subset I want my scatter point to have a size of 29 and 62 (as std) on x and 
## y-axis, respectively (so basically an oval) with centre at 104 and 124 (as mean) on x and y respectively. 
## Since the count is 28, I want my scatter point to be relatively bigger than 
## previous (based on this count throughout the analysis). The values of mean TC 
## would be used as the colour axis (same as Fig. 1).
```

**Closest I got to my goal:**

```
P_range = np.arange(0,4000,200); RZ_range = np.arange(0,1000,50); TC_range = np.arange(0,110,10)

x = []; y = []; z = []; height = []; width = []; size = [] 
for i in range(P_range.shape[0]):
    for j in range(RZ_range.shape[0]):
        for k in range(TC_range.shape[0]):
            stats = RZS_P[(RZS_P.PRP>= P_range[i]-100) & (RZS_P.PRP< P_range[i]+100) & (RZS_P.RZ>= RZ_range[j]-25) & 
                          (RZS_P.RZ< RZ_range[j]+25) & (RZS_P.TC>= TC_range[k]-5) & (RZS_P.TC< TC_range[k]+5)].describe()
            x.append(stats.to_numpy()[1,1]) 
            y.append(stats.to_numpy()[1,0])
            z.append(stats.to_numpy()[1,2])
            width.append(stats.to_numpy()[2,1])
            height.append(stats.to_numpy()[2,0])
            size.append(stats.to_numpy()[0,0])

final_scatters = pd.DataFrame({'PRP': x, 'RZ': y, 'TC': z, 'height': height, 'width': width, 'size': size})
#final_scatters looks like this
    PRP         RZ          TC           height      width      size
22  84.423500   91.315781   2.492503    17.500629   18.499458   2.0
33  61.671188   137.650848  1.305071    18.169079   20.138525   6.0
143 53.673630   634.536926  3.443243    1.000000    1.000000    1.0
231 202.459641  62.480145   2.156926    8.962382    46.061661   21.0
242 217.588333  98.111694   2.011893    15.964933   59.468643   20.0
....................................................................

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))

points = plt.scatter(final_scatters.PRP, final_scatters.RZ, c=final_scatters.TC, cmap="Spectral",
                     s = final_scatters['size']*40, vmax = 100, vmin =0, alpha = 0.9, edgecolors= 'black')
plt.colorbar(points)
```

[image]

Now I am doing following for ellipse, but getting an empty box:

```
ells = [Ellipse(xy = np.array([np.array(final_scatters)[i,0], np.array(final_scatters)[i,1]]), width=np.array(final_scatters)[i,4], 
                height=np.array(final_scatters)[i,3]) for i in range(len(final_scatters))]
fig = plt.figure(0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for e in ells:
    ax.add_artist(e)
    e.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
    e.set_alpha(rnd.rand())
    e.set_facecolor(rnd.rand(3))
```

Comment: I think there are several problems here. If I understand correctly, first you need to cluster your data points and/or exclude outliers. Only then you can aggregate clusters into unique circles and compute their size

Comment: @Vincent. I do not want to exclude the outliers, but I do want to cluster the data points based on 3 variables. I need a dynamic coding scheme for that as mentioned 'combine some of the same looking points in the neighbourhood with a PRP (± 100), RZ (± 50) and TC (± 5)'. I think you got the gist of that. I am not coding capable of clustering points based on 3 variables. Can you provide some help or insight to that?

Comment: For plotting purpose, I think you need to cluster. In your example, you come from 10 yellow points to 2 yellow circles. My term for this is clustering, I don't really see what else you can do

Comment: @Vincent. Sorry, let me rephrase. I am actually not trying to cluster and shape of my scatter is unrelated to the problem. Let me add some additional information up there.

Comment: Added the coding I have in my mind but need help in coding that for visualizing large dataset.

Comment: So is this just a plotting question ? Have you seen this ? https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_demo.html

Comment: Yes, this would be similar. Thanks, I'll look into this.

Comment: @Vincent....I added some edits related to the ellipse. Would you be able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `final_scatters` dataframe is well structured with one line by expected ellipse :

```
final_scatters = pd.DataFrame({'PRP': x, 'RZ': y, 'TC': z, 'height': height, 'width': width, 'size': size})
#final_scatters looks like this
    PRP         RZ          TC           height      width      size
22  84.423500   91.315781   2.492503    17.500629   18.499458   2.0
33  61.671188   137.650848  1.305071    18.169079   20.138525   6.0
143 53.673630   634.536926  3.443243    1.000000    1.000000    1.0
231 202.459641  62.480145   2.156926    8.962382    46.061661   21.0
242 217.588333  98.111694   2.011893    15.964933   59.468643   20.0
```

You can iterate through it row by row and plot the ellipses :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplot()

for i, row in final_scatters.iterrows():
    ax.add_artist(Ellipse(
        xy = (row['PRP'], row['RZ']),
        width = row['width'], 
        height = row['height'],
        alpha = 0.5  # in case you want some transparency 
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks, Vincent. It seems that I was missing `plt.axis([-5, 4000, -5, 900])`, which is quite troublesome when using `patches` (even with your code).